# Increase in field length will result in data loss ?

Tags: firebird, string-length, fieldtype

If we increase the field width (say varchar(7) to varchar(20)) will it result in data loss?

This is to be done in Firebird 1.5 database.

Answer (score 3):

No, as you are increasing the size of the column there will be no data loss.

Of course you should, if at all possible, first do this on a copy of your production database to ensure you are happy with the result.

Comment: +1 for the backup advice. Even for the most innocuous operation, if there's a shadow of a doubt, take a backup. Especially for data definition statements, which can't usually be rolled back in transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Not if you are increasing the size:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER c1 TYPE char(90);
```

[Reducing is always the problem](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq285/).

You should look at using [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org/) as an administrative tool to manage dependencies and simplify working with FireBird.